# Hibernate 4 Distinct and order by together

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, hibernate

```
select distinct groupMember.proUcer.proUserDetail 
from proGroupMembership groupMember 
where groupMember.proGroup.id =:groupId and groupMember.status = 1 
order by groupMember.proUcer.proUserDetail.firstName
```

ORA-01791 Exception 
coming when i execute this Query.
After many research i got solution to solve this problem by selecting one more column on which we are applying order by -
So i convert query according that solution

```
select distinct groupMember.proUcer.proUserDetail, groupMember.proUcer.proUserDetail.firstName 
from proGroupMembership groupMember 
where groupMember.proGroup.id =:groupId and groupMember.status = 1 
order by groupMember.proUcer.proUserDetail.firstName
```

Now my problem is I only need list of object but **query.list()** returning list of array of object.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you need only distinct groupMember.proUcer.proUserDetail in output and not groupMember.proUcer.proUserDetail.firstName??

Comment: Yes Utsav i only need list of groupMember.proUcer.proUserDetail .

Comment: Ok. I am not java/hibernate person, but if you are using Oracle 11+ then this should work.
`with tbl(proUserDetail) as (*your second query*) select proUserDetail from tbl`
Please let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: No I am using oracle 10g. will it work in oracle 10g?

Comment: give it a try. Replace ... with your remaining second query. I just used an alias for distinct column name

`with tbl as (select distinct groupMember.proUcer.proUserDetail as distUserDetail, <....rest of the second query> ) select distUserDetail from tbl`

Comment: @Utsav The query in the question is not a SQL query. It's a JPQL query. What you suggest is not JPQL, it's SQL.

Comment: Thanks utsav but @JB is right.

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeat yourself in the query like that. Use joins:

```
select distinct proUserDetail 
from proGroupMembership groupMember 
join groupMember.proUcer proUcer
join proUcer.proUserDetail proUserDetail
where groupMember.proGroup.id = :groupId and groupMember.status = 1 
order by proUserDetail.firstName
```

Comment: Thanks, But it's not working. Hibernate Exception coming like  proGroupMembership is not mapped [select distinct ..

Comment: Hey @JB now its working for me. I was using table name instead of Entity name. Thanks

Comment: Hey @JB I have used this Query but its returning extra rows(More than expected). do you have any idea why?